# New Review system currently in beta testing

Tags: discussion, review

A new system for [reviewing posts that require moderation](https://android.stackexchange.com/review) is now live here at Android Enthusiasts.

For details, please see [the post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta).

It's important to note that this is not (necessarily) a tool for Community Moderators. It's a tool to help the Community moderate itself. Please check it out and lend a hand.

If you have issues and questions, please post them on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review), not here. (Be sure to use the "review" tag as well.)

2012-09-14: [New review queue: First posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988)

Answer (score 2):

This is a new and interesting feature that allows users to spend less effort while doing their part to this community network.

The new feature, as any other feature comes with potential bad habits that one may get caught in without noticing.

Some that I've noticed across SE are:

- **Clicker happy**

  Experienced users or new users all get involved in such a way that may forget about the real purpose of the review area. Take you time, analyze what you are reviewing:

  [Is there an actual “accept ALL the suggested edits” problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140017/184576)
- **The usage for competition**

  One interesting part of the new review is that we are able to view who's the top reviewer, what position are we in, and even compare decisions by looking at the review history.

  [image: Stats]

  This serves the purpose of providing users a way to improve themselves and refrain from committing mistakes, by learning with others.

  It is not the Olympic Games, there's no fat payment for the first place, so, don't go voting just because! Vote and review always with the community shirt on.
- **Exaggerated point of view**

  One may get addicted, and as any addiction, there are side effects. If you're tired of seeing what you consider bad answers or bad questions, take a break from review, use the chat to exchange ideas, post a question at META to clarify you point of view.

  Remember the famous: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/184576)

  *Don't spend your precious time reviewing just to feel tired and saturated.*

---

<sup>I'm answering this as to illustrate some of the frequent problems I see on the several SE sites, being discussed on META, and even some that I've personally experienced and/or have been confronted by. Feel free to improve it.</sup>

Comment: Two observations of my own from trawling in the "Low Quality" queue: 1. I had no idea there was that much _crap_ on here. 2. Who the hell upvotes this stuff?

Comment: @AlEverett New users tend to leave low quality posts, and the same goes for their perspective regarding what's a good Q or A to upvote :) *Today I found one answer written in French :D*

Answer (score 0):

Converting Zuul's "clicker happy" to "trigger happy", I'd like to see the old system available even when the last queue was converted, as I already explained with a post on meta ([Is there a way to access the older review tools for processing the edit queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144964/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-older-review-tools-for-processing-the-edit-queue/147229#147229)). While feeling comfortable with the new system when it comes to close-votes, I prefer the old system for some of the others: There I can pick the questions I feel I can do something about, leaving the others completely untouched (so I can even return to them later, which is not possible with the new system).

Don't get me wrong: the new system has its advantages. But so has the old... My favorite quote here again:

> As it stands now, I rarely touch the edit queue unless I'm really bored because I don't want to have to wade through a ton of questions that I can't necessarily help with.

This I can easier avoid with the old system. Add a possibility to filter by tag, or to suppress unwanted tags (such as favorite tags and ignored tags in the questions section, or even just honoring those in the review section), so it will even help when we get bigger ;)